# Nginx can't run Rails page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I want to use `nginx` as my Rails development server.I installed  `nginx` and `passenger`.

My nginx configuration file is :

```
http{
      passenger_root /home/hxh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.26;
      passenger_ruby /home/hxh/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448/ruby;
      include       mime.types;
      default_type  application/octet-stream;
      server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root /home/hxh/share/ruby/sport;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env development;
       }
}
```

But when I run the server,I got the error:

```
404 Not Found

nginx/1.4.4
```

why the nginx didn't identify the Rails page.

Comment: Is sport is your rails application root directory?

Comment: Yes,I can sure this.Because I have placed a html file in this directory,and I can visit this page in broswer.

Comment: Good, Try my below configuration, It's supposed to work. You was missing few configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to point the `root` to the public folder, if `/home/hxh/share/ruby/sport` is indeed your project folder, then replace it with `/home/hxh/share/ruby/sport/public`

Comment: Thanks,I was careless.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing couple of settings.

Try with below configuration, It supposed to work.

```
http {
  passenger_root /home/hxh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.26;
  passenger_ruby /home/hxh/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448/ruby;
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  passenger_max_pool_size 10;
  access_log  off;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  gzip  on;


  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
      root   /home/hxh/share/ruby/sport/public;
      passenger_enabled on;
      rails_env production;
    }
  }
}
```

Note:

1. Your are missing **location**
2. Your application root should point public folder
3. Application root directory should have full execution permission

Comment: Thanks for your answer,the issue is my `root` should set to `/home/hxh/share/ruby/sport/public`.And after my test,the `location` isn't necessary.